# Extract data from a nested row in Athena/Presto

Tags: sql, row, amazon-athena, presto

I have data which is being represented as an array of row(value varchar).  The arrays are variable length, but I would like to extract them into their own columns, or into an array of varchar.

Despite `typeof()` saying this data is a row, I don't seem to be able to access it directly.   Can I convert data of type `row(value varchar)` directly to a varchar?  Or do the same with the array?

`SELECT records[1], records FROM recorddata`

```
_col0  _col1
{value=data1}   [{value=data1}, {value=data2}, {value=data3}, {value=data4}]
{value=data6}   [{value=data6}, {value=data7}]
```

`SELECT typeof(records[1]), typeof(records) FROM recorddata`

```
_col0   _col1
1   row(value varchar)  array(row(value varchar))
2   row(value varchar)  array(row(value varchar))
3   row(value varchar)  array(row(value varchar))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with this more, it seems that the answer is to cast these fields to json which turns them into arrays of varchar.

```
SELECT cast(records[1] as json), cast(records as json) FROM recorddata
```

results:

```
_col0  _col1
["data1"]   ["data1", "data2"], "data3", "data4"]
["data6"]   ["data6", "data7"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`transform`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?#transform) and accessing `value` should do the trick:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
           (ARRAY[CAST(ROW('data1') AS ROW(value varchar)), CAST(ROW('data2') AS ROW(value varchar))]),
           (ARRAY[CAST(ROW('data3') AS ROW(value varchar)), CAST(ROW('data4') AS ROW(value varchar))])                    
         ) AS t (records))

SELECT transform(records, x -> x.value)
FROM
    dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [data1, data2] |
| [data3, data4] |